# Why did this question receive so many down-votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I'm new to this site, so I'm not familiar with the community's standards for what makes a question good or bad. Why did the question ["*Putting the title bar at the bottom of the dialog?*"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/64596/95390) receive so many down-votes? I don't think it's too bad of a question, even if the answer is pretty clearly "*that's a bad idea.*"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what makes a good question, you could take a look [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

As for the question you mentioned. It is a proper question else it would have been closed, but the question is probably not popular because the original poster (OP) is basically asking other people to research for him. He's not specifically asking their expert opinion in the matter, just "where can I find research".

That is my guess as to why it has received so many down-votes.